# Git merge two repositories

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket, git-merge

I was a question regarding merging two git repositories.

The one git repository, let's name it X, is being hosted on GitHub and is lead by one team member. While the other on BitBucket and being lead by myself.

You must be asking yourself why exactly are we doing so? The main reason is that we are migrating to BitBucket, while some work was still done in the meantime on both repositories.

To cut the story short, I want to merge these two repositories - without having to handle conflicts.

I've ran onto numerous posts on StackOverflow that explain how to do this, but unfortunately, none of them helped.

Any advice or references?

Comment: What do you mean by "without having to handle conflicts"? If you are merging any diverged code, there is a good chance that you will encounter conflicts if conflicting changes exist in the two repositories. You won't be able to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

You will certainly have conflict to resolve.

You can create a new git repository ans make an initial commit:

```
mkdir newRepository
git init
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit .gitignore -m 'init'
```

Then fetch and merge the first repo (let's say github)

```
git remote add first pathTo/first
git fetch first
git merge first/master
```

Then fetch and merge the second (bitbucket):

```
git remote add second pathTo/second
git fetch second
git merge second/master
```

Then push all of it to a new bitbucket repo.